# Displaced circuits with PGF 3.0.0

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}

        PGF version: \pgfversion
        \vspace{1em}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]    
            \draw
                node{} (0,1)
                to [contact={at end, fill=white}] (0,1)
                to [contact=at end] node[pos=.5, above]{} (1,1);
            \draw
                node{} (1,2)
                to [contact=at end] (1,2)
                to [contact=at end] (1,1)
                to [contact=at end] (1,0);
            \draw
                node{} (5,2)
                to [contact=at end] (5,2)
                to [contact=at end] (5,1)
                to [contact=at end] (5,0);
            \draw
                node{} (5,1)
                to [contact=at end] (5,1)
                to [contact={at end, fill=white}] (6,1);
            \draw
                node{} (1,2)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,2);
            \draw
                node{} (1,1)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,1);
            \draw
                node{} (1,0)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

When compiled with MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit using PGF 2.10, the following result is yield:

[image: Compiled MWE with PGF 2.10]

After updating my MiKTeX installation and upgrade of the PGF package to version 3.0.0 the output is the following:

[image: Compiled MWE with PGF 3.0.0]

As you may notice, several lines are displaced as well as the open contacts are not displayed correctly anymore.

I just want to ask for confirmation whether this is a bug in the PGF 3.0.0 package or if I am doing something wrong. In case it is, I will file a bug report at PGF's bugtracker at sourceforge.net.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same results than you (straight lines with PGF 2.10 in OSX, TeXlive 2012, incorrect lines with PGF 3.0.0 in Ubuntu, TeXlive 2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the observed behaviour can be considered a bug, because I'm  not familiar with the "proper" syntax for circuits.

I would write the code in a different way (which does not imply that yours is wrong, since as I stated I don't know the "right" syntax). This is my version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}

        PGF version: \pgfversion
        \vspace{1em}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
            \draw  (0,1) node [contact,fill=white] {}
                to (1,1);
            \draw  (1,2) node[contact] {}
                to (1,1) node[contact] {}
                to (1,0) node[contact] {};
            \draw  (5,2) node[contact] {}
                to (5,1) node[contact] {}
                to (5,0) node[contact] {} ;
            \draw  (5,1)
                to (6,1) node[contact, fill=white] {};
            \draw  (1,2)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,2);
            \draw  (1,1)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,1);
            \draw  (1,0)
                to [resistor={style={circuit symbol size=width 10 height 2.5}}] (5,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I find that `contact` has to be considered a node, to which lines are connected, and not part of a `to` specification as you wrote in your example. A point in favour of my version is that it produces the same result both in PGF2.10 and PGF3.0 :-)

[image: PGF 2.10]

[image: PGF 3.0]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am a beginner with TikZ/PGF, so I think my syntax is simply wrong and it was just a pure coincidence that my code worked with PGF 2.10. Thank you for this hint!